# Text in search bar disappears when search button on keyboard is clicked in iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, searchbar

After typing text in the search bar of iPhone, when search button is clicked on the keyboard, the text disappears. I've added `<UISearchDisplayDelegate, UISearchBarDelegate>` and `BOOL isSearching;`

```
- (void)searchBarTextDidBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {
    isSearching = YES;
}

- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText {
     NSLog(@"Text change - %d",isSearching);
     NSString *str = searchBar.text;
     self.searchDisplayController.searchBar.text = str;
     //Remove all objects first.
     [filteredArray removeAllObjects];

     if([searchText length] != 0) {
         isSearching = YES;
         [self searchTableList];
     }
     else {
         isSearching = NO;
     }
     [self.tableView1 reloadData];
}

- (void)searchBarCancelButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {
  NSLog(@"Cancel clicked");
}

- (void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {
   [self searchTableList];
   [searchBar resignFirstResponder];
}
- (void)searchTableList {
    searchString = searchBar.text;

    for (NSString *tempStr in tableData) {
        NSComparisonResult result = [tempStr compare:searchString options:   (NSCaseInsensitiveSearch|NSDiacriticInsensitiveSearch) range:NSMakeRange(0, [searchString length])];
        if (result == NSOrderedSame) {
            [filteredArray addObject:tempStr];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see anything that may be causing that behavior... Is there anything else in your code where the search bar is being manipulated?

Comment: No i'm not using any other methods for search bar

Answer (score 2):

Swift 4.0:

I had the same issue, but I resolved by defining the UISearchBarDelegate method i.e. searchBarTextDidEndEditing

```
func searchBarTextDidEndEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {

}
```

Without writing any code in method.
I hope this answer will help you.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with UISearchController.
I prevented the search controller clearing the text storing it in a String and later, after deactivating the controller, assigning the stored text to the search bar.

Objective C:

```
-(void) searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {
    NSString *text = searchBar.text;
    [self.searchController setActive:NO animated:YES];
    self.searchController.searchBar.text = text;
}
```

Swift 2.X:

```
func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    let text = searchBar.text
    searchController.active = false
    searchController.searchBar.text = text
}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Swift 5

```
func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    searchBar.resignFirstResponder()
}
```